# IntelliJ -- Show class structure... of a different class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ comes with the capability of showing a class' "structure", i.e. the list of all signatures of methods and properties arranged neatly into a sortable overview.

Problem is that once displayed, it will change to display the structure for whatever class is active. Meaning if you have two classes opened in split-view and you want to work on one looking at the structure of the other ... you can't. Or at least you can't without constantly switching back to the other class.

Is there a way to "lock" the structure view to a certain class?

Comment: I don't know a way to pin the class structure viewer to a certain class. Maybe @crazycoder knows a way to do that. Otherwise feel free to open a feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already feature request created on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178175

Comment: First requested 7 years ago ... looks like this isn't going to be a priority anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. You could fold all methods of the class source so that only the method signatures remain, but that is not sortable.